# appengine select based on timestamp

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I can't seem to select something based on timestamp.  The behavior is a bit weird and the < and = symbols don't seem to mean what I expect them to.

```
""" A site message """
class Message( db.Model ) :
  # from/to/ a few other fields
  subject = db.StringProperty()
  body = db.Text()

  # this is the field i'm trying to use
  sent = db.DateTimeProperty( auto_now_add=True )
```

When I write GQL queries like

```
select * from Message where sent = '2009-09-14 01:00:02.648000'
```

(there is a message with PRECISELY that time stamp in the datastore)

it gives me *nothing* back.

If I try

```
select * from Message where sent < '2009-09-14 01:00:02.648000'
```

It simply gives me all of them.  When I try the > sign, it simply gives me none again.

What's going on here and how do I select based on timestamp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do **NOT** use strings to "stand in" for datetimes!  It just won't work...

See [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html): `DateTimeProperty` corresponds to a [datetime.datetime](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#datetime) value.  `import datetime`, convert your beloved strings to `datetime.datetime` instances (e.g. by calling the `strptime` method thereof), use THOSE instances for comparisons -- and, of course, live happily ever after!-)

Comment: How do you put an object into a GQL query string without converting it back into a string though?

Comment: You can reference datetime like so: SELECT * FROM table WHERE datemodel = DATETIME('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') 

See here: code.google.com/appengine/docs/…

Comment: You can also do "SELECT * FROM table WHERE datemodel = :1", and pass the datetime as an argument to gqlquery, which is definitely what you _should_ do if you're using a datetime selected at runtime.